# Django: Auto suggest using Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, autosuggest, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch-dsl to index data in elasticsearch index. I am am using following class to create elasticsearch document:

```
class BooksDoc(Document):

    title = Text(
        analyzer=my_analyzer
    )
    author = Text(
        analyzer=my_analyzer
    )
    publisher = Text(
        analyzer=my_analyzer
    )
    image_url = Text(analyzer=my_analyzer)
    price = Text(analyzer=my_analyzer)
    category =Text(analyzer=my_analyzer)
    published = Boolean()
    upload_date = Text()
    class Index:
        name = 'books'
```

Here is my analyzer:

```
my_analyzer = analyzer('my_analyzer',
    tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'edge_ngram', min_gram=1, max_gram=20),
    filter=['lowercase']
)
```

I am using following function to index document:

```
    def indexing(self):
    doc = BooksDoc(
        meta={'id': self.id},
        title=self.book_title,
        author=self.book_author,
        publisher=self.book_publisher,
        image_url=self.front_image,
        price=self.book_price,
        catagory=__catagory,
        published=self.isPublished,
        upload_date=self.dateadded
    )
    try:
        doc.save()
        return doc.to_dict(include_meta=True)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return None
```

I want to implement search such that when user enters a search string i can query elasticsearch and fetch all the records where i find a match. For example, if user enters "Boo" then all the records containing string "Boo" should be returned.Right now search works fine when string matches exactly in elasticsearch but i also want to fetch record if there is a partial match. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what query you are using. Typically if you are using `edge_ngram` you want to specify a different analyzer for search so that the `edge_ngram` is not applied to the input. Then you can use a standard `match` query.

For auto-suggest though it is much better (more performant) to use `Completion` field and completion suggester (0, 1).

0 - https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me
1 - http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#suggestions

Comment: I want to do it using edge_ngrams but i dont don't know how to write analyzer for it